# Cannot set default value of a field in an Access Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to set a default value of a field in an access table in Table Design. The test I entered is:

```
=DLookUp([Tbl::VII::A::03::b_stkIden].[stkTersNam]","[Tbl::VII::A::03::b_stkIden]","[stkIdx]= [stkIdenOld]") where
```

In the different attempts the text was typed (did not work), copied and pasted (did not work). Keeps saying Default value or Validation rule is invalid.

`stkIden` is the source table containing the value I need
`stkTersNam` is the field which contains the value I need
`stkIdx` is the index field of my target table in which I want to insert the lookup value
`stkIdenOld` is the index field in the source table …stkIden.

It seems that default value attribute of tables in Access 2019 no longer accepts any references to any Table in the current database. It seems strange the Ms would remove this essential functionality. Is this just a quirk of the Jet Engine.

Please help. I am desperate. Should I consider abandoning Access for some other more user friendly database.

Comment: What is `where` doing there at the end? -- `[stkIdenOld]` can't be resolved in your expression.

Comment: What would you consider more user-friendly than Access? Switching to another db app won't resolve. This is improper use of DefaultValue property.

Comment: Was thinking a stored procedure in MS SQL Server

Comment: Thank you I will try the SQL statement for the combo box again This time with extra caution.  Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Should not have 'where' at end of expression. Don't put parameter within quote marks - concatenate dynamic parameter. Missing quote mark for the field argument.

`=DLookUp("[stkTersNam]", "[Tbl::VII::A::03::b_stkIden]", "[stkIdx]=" & [stkIdenOld])`

If stkIdx is a text field, use apostrophe delimiters.

`=DLookUp("[stkTersNam]", "[Tbl::VII::A::03::b_stkIden]", "[stkIdx]='" & [stkIdenOld] & "'")`

However, this won't work as a DefaultValue (won't in any version of Access) and really makes no sense to pull related info via DefaultValue property anyhow. Options:
Query joining tables.
Multi-column combobox on form.
DLookup in textbox ControlSource.

Comment: Thank you I tried that but access Jet engine does not seem to resolve the criteria component of the query i.e. matching the index value of the target table [stkIdx] to index value of the source [stkIdenOld]. The jet engine is very skittish for it tries to control SQL injections. I am pleased that MS is doing due diligence on the subject matter, but as developers we do need extract or simply present associated values to end-user needs so that they have a complete perspective

Comment: As I said, won't work in DefaultValue property but the other options do work.